# Is there any way to get correct system time without NTP?

Tags: linux, kernel, time, clock, timer

I'm developing industrial embedded device on the ARMv7, 3.10 kernel.

First, before taking up the main subject, let me talk about hardware time. Amlogic meson8b is core unit, so i used "aml-rtc" as main rtc, but it was unreliable. so, we decided external rtc chip, and now ds1340 is main rtc. after few test sequence, i think hardware time is now pretty reliable.

The problem is about system time. system time is running faster than h/w time about 2~3secs/day. as you know, there are many solutions using NTP, but because of charateristic of our device, it is disconnected from ethernet, so i can't use NTP.

**The point is that i want know if there are any method for getting correct system time without NTP.**

Thank you for read this thread, and sorry to my poor english.

---

ps. I thought also using call "hwclock --hctosys" periodically, but this can be a critical problem because of save files and logs. for example, LOG<1> saved at 12:05 system time, and if hwclock set system back to 12:04, LOG<1> could be lost cause of new logs saved after 'new time' reach to 12:05.
 this is just a example, and also i can solve this problem by set "hwclock --hctosys" period very short, but i wish to keep this way as the last resort.

Comment: You can get accurate time via GPS.

Comment: Obviously, you have some way of measuring the error (as you say that it is about 2~3secs/day).  Some (most? all?) NTP (client) software works by speeding up or slowing down the system clock so it synchronizes with the external time source (rather than jumping the clock forward or backward).  Some NTP software will allow you to configure the error rate it should assume if it can't contact an NTP server; you may be able to set this directly in a config file. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  An alternative would be to connect it to the Internet for a few days, so it learns how fast the system clock is; then see whether it continues to adjust the clock correctly after it is disconnected.

Comment: Unless you have a local, self-powered reference clock or use an external reference such as NTP, any other scheme will probably have at least one failure scenario that causes your system to not have accurate time.  @G-Man 's "alternate" scheme won't work because oscillators/crystals are not that stable over long intervals.  The AC power line frequency (60 or 50 Hz) is more accurate (i.e. it's actively managed).

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

My original answer involves some programming. Maybe you can make the whole setup simpler with some other programming. On my Kubuntu `man ntpdate` shows that it uses `adjtime()` system call to gradually adjust the system clock. Consider a program that reads hardware clock and calls `adjtime()`.

---

#### Original answer

From G-Man's comment:

> Some (most? all?) NTP (client) software works by speeding up or slowing down the system clock so it synchronizes with the external time source.

If that is the right way to cope with log issues etc., maybe you can implement fake local NTP server. Let your fake NTP server <strike>do corrections to itself (e.g.) once an hour using hardware clock</strike> read hardware clock; then let NTP client adjust the system clock in a way that doesn't disturb logs and save files.